# txfontsb small caps

Tags: fonts, small-caps

For some reason I get an error message when using `\textsc{}` with `txfontsb.sty`. It can be my installation but since `txfonts.sty` is working I am bewildered. The MWE is here:

```
  \documentclass{article}

% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[LY1]{fontenc}
% \usepackage{txfonts}%  works
  \usepackage{txfontsb}% error message

  \begin{document}
  \textsc{Hello world.}%
  \end{document}
```

As you see I have also tried using `T1` instead of `LY1` (without success). The error message I get is

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LY1/txrc/m/sc' undefined
```

My font directory listings are

```
texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/txfontsb:

lgrtxr.fd   lgrtxrc.fd  lgrtxry.fd  lgrtxryc.fd 
ot1txrc.fd  ot1txryc.fd txfontsb.sty

texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/txfonts:

ly1txr.fd   omltxmi.fd  omstxsy.fd  ot1txss.fd  
t1txss.fd   ts1txss.fd  utxexa.fd   utxss.fd    
utxsyc.fd   ly1txss.fd  omltxr.fd   omxtxex.fd  
ot1txtt.fd  t1txtt.fd   ts1txtt.fd  utxmia.fd   
utxsya.fd   utxtt.fd    ly1txtt.fd  omstxr.fd   
ot1txr.fd   t1txr.fd    ts1txr.fd   txfonts.sty 
utxr.fd utxsyb.fd
```

Any clues?

Comment: This is not an error but only a warning. Your font doesn't have a scshape and so LaTeX will fall back to another font.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. What I don't understand is why this happens. The manual states that SC is included.

Comment: The package can only be used with OT1-encoding. There are no support files for T1 or LY1 - which imho makes it quite useless.

Comment: I am quite embarrassed. Should have noticed it myself... Do you know about an alternative to txfontsb? My particular needs are: more ink to the letters than e.g. CM, bold greek letters, a good collection of math operators and not-so-wide but still good-looking equations.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ... or LGR encoding, which seems to be the main use case: writing greek text with `txfontsb`.

Comment: Seems like I have a long way to go. I need to read up on font encoding in LaTeX. Have never understood it, really. Anyway, thanks for taking your time answering my questions.

Comment: You might like to have a look at the `newtx` package, it seems to fulfil your needs. I personally add `mtpro2` to it for the math, but give `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` a try.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error but only a warning. Your font doesn't have a scshape and so LaTeX will fall back to another font.

Also the package can only be used with OT1-encoding. There are no support files for T1 or LY1 - which imho makes it quite useless.